# Deleting foreign key referenced ID

Tags: database, reference, foreign-keys

I have a large database, and as expected, with a lot of foreign keys referencing tables. From a database design perspective, how should I handle the deletion of a record that is referenced by a foreign key?

One option I thought of was adding a boolean column to the table which determines whether the record is active or not. So if I was to delete a record, I'd just set its boolean active value to false.

Database may end up being bloated, but then not only will all the referenced foreign keys remain unchanged, the database will hold more information.

I would like to hear your thoughts on this matter regarding a system critical database.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question, you have 2 tables:

```
| main  |               |     child     |
|-------|               |---------------|
|id|data| (1) ----> (n) |id|main_id (FK)|
```

And you don't want to delete the data from main table, when there are records in the child table.

You didn't say, what RDBMS you use. But in MySQL you can set up the foreign key type. If you set it to RESTRICT, then the system won't allow you to delete the data from the main table, if there is data in child table.

Or you can set it to CASCADE, then when you delete the data in main table, it will be automatically deleted from the child table.

So there is no need to create additional 'active' field.

Comment: Excuse me not being clear. I'm using Postgres and I know how to DELETE CASCADE. I was mainly looking at the application as whole, and the deletion of entries such as in a user table, which is referenced by many foreign keys throughout the database. From experience, is it advisable to delete entries from such tables? Wouldn't it simply increase the possibility of corrupt data, as opposed to adding the active boolean column to the user table? Is this a good design in such an instance?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to Your question is highly dependent on Your application.

If You need "historic" data, then using an "enabled"-flag seems the right choice. However, if there is sensitive data in Your database and You want to ensure that deleted data is not too easy to recover, then an "enabled"-flag is a no-go.

Other aspects:

- Do You need "undelete"?
- How often do delete operations occur? Many deletes create many disabled entries.
- Is there an easy way (e.g., database triggers) to ensure that entries referencing disabled
  entries are disabled as well?
- Do You have processes or mechanisms to ensure that applications will only see/handle enabled entries? Consider views.
- Consider creating proper indices to speed up looking for enabled entries and need a lot of space.
- Do You have requirements (technical, organizational, legal) for finally removing
  deleted entries? Do You need the deletion date for that purpose?
- Is there a need for a cleanup-script?

I know, a lot of questions. However, I hope those questions will help You to find an answer to Your question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The whole idea of my application is to keep as much information available without having to do through paper work and files, so I'm going to have to opt for the enable-flag. My database has almost 250 tables, and it will be critical, so I hope that my DB Server will be able to handle all this data. Thanks again.